# jest test for a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-redux, jestjs

I have created a custom hook to display a notification message and remove it after 2 seconds.
I want to write a test for this. I'm new to writing tests and not entirely sure how to write a test for this. Can anyone help me?

my hook

```
export function useNotification() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const notifications = useSelector(getNotificationsState);
  function toast(type, message) {
    const id = notifications.toasts.length;
    const data = { type, message, id };
    dispatch({
      type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.ADD_TOAST,
      payload: data,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.REMOVE_TOAST,
        payload: id,
      });
    }, NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT);
  }

  return toast;
}
```

I want to write the test for above hook

```
describe('useNotification', () => {
    //Actual test
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this snippet can help

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

jest.useFakeTimers(); 

const mockedUseDispatch = jest.fn();
const mockedUseSelector = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: mockedUseSelector,
  useDispatch: mockedUseDispatch
}));

describe('useNotification', () => {
    it('Should show and dismiss toast', () => {
       //arrange
       useSelector.mockImplementation((getNotificationsState) => getNotificationsState(yourMockedStoreData));

       //act
       const toast = useNotification()
       toast(type, message) //type, message are your own data

       //assert
       expect(toast).toHaveBeenCallTimes(1)
       expect(toast).toHaveBeenCallWith({
         type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.ADD_TOAST,
         payload: data, //your expected data
       })

      // Fast-forward
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT);
      
      expect(toast).toHaveBeenCallTimes(2)
      expect(toast).toHaveBeenCallWith({
         type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.ADD_TOAST,
         payload: id, //your expected data
      })
    })
});
```

Note that I cannot run it with your setup, so I tried to give you the basic understanding about how to implement an unit test for custom hook.

Some references

https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#advance-timers-by-time

https://dev.to/coderjay06/the-three-a-s-of-unit-testing-b22

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock third-party libraries. Mock implementation will break their functions. In your case, the `useSelector`and `useDispatch` hooks' functions are broken if you mock it with just a `jest.fn()`.

See the original implementation of [`useSelector`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v8.0.7/src/hooks/useSelector.ts#L38) hook, you can't simply provide a mock implementation for it. It has validation logic, context switch logic, and call [`useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.2.0/packages/use-sync-external-store/src/useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector.js#L19) hook internally to subscribe the changes of redux store.

That's why we should test the `useSelector` hook's function, not its implementation. Implementations often change, and testing implementations can make test code fragile.

Instead, we can test the function of React custom hook, not the implementation.

Here, we can use [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/) to test React custom hooks. We also create a mock store using the `createStore` function from redux for testing.

E.g.

`useNotification.ts`:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const getNotificationsState = state => state.notifications;

export const NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS = {
  ADD_TOAST: 'ADD_TOAST',
  REMOVE_TOAST: 'REMOVE_TOAST'
}
export const NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT = 3000;

export function useNotification() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const notifications = useSelector(getNotificationsState);
  function toast(type, message) {
    const id = notifications.toasts.length;
    const data = { type, message, id };
    dispatch({ type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.ADD_TOAST, payload: data });

    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.REMOVE_TOAST, payload: id });
    }, NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT);
  }

  return toast;
}
```

`useNotification.test.tsx`:

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS, NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT, useNotification } from "./useNotification";
import React from "react";

describe('useNotification', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  })
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  })
  test('should pass', () => {
    const rootReducer = (state = { notifications: { toasts: [] as any[] } }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.ADD_TOAST:
          return { ...state, notifications: { toasts: [...state.notifications.toasts, action.payload] } }
        case NOTIFICATION_ACTIONS.REMOVE_TOAST:
          return { ...state, notifications: { toasts: state.notifications.toasts.filter(t => t.id !== action.payload) } }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
    const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
    const { result } = renderHook(useNotification, { wrapper });

    act(() => {
      result.current('a', 'ok');
    })
    expect(store.getState()).toEqual({ notifications: { toasts: [{ message: 'ok', type: 'a', id: 0 }] } });

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT);
    })

    expect(store.getState()).toEqual({ notifications: { toasts: [] } });
  })
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/71351220/useNotification.test.tsx (19.078 s)
  useNotification
    ✓ should pass (29 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useNotification.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.804 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
```